# Reading and writing RData files in Julia

Tags: julia

I googled but couldn't find any functions in Julia that can read and write R's RData (RDa) files. Is there any library / function / package that can allow me to do this? There appears to be a RDA.jl file in the src directory of DataFrames but I didn't find any mention of this in the DataFrames documentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function you are looking for is read_rda which comes with the DataFrames package. So,

```
read_rda(filename)
```

should work and return a Dict with variable names => data.

Comment: is there any function that can write a rda file (e.g. write_rda)?

Comment: I recommend passing in the keyword parameter **convertdataframes** as well to automatically convert things to julia DataFrames objects: `read_rda("some_data_file.dat",convertdataframes=true)`

Comment: This function does exist in the DataFrames package.

Comment: I believe `read_rda` is no longer a function in (at least) v0.22.7 of the DataFrames package. However, I've been using the [RData.jl](https://github.com/JuliaData/RData.jl) package to load .rda files in Julia.