# Gzip error when reading R data files into julia

Tags: r, dataframe, gzip, julia

I'm getting an error from gzip when reading an R data file.  I'm trying to use the approach described here: [Reading and writing RData files in Julia](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21860053/reading-and-writing-rdata-files-in-julia).

Here's a minimal example.  In R, I run the following script:

```
var1 <- matrix( runif(9), 3, 3 )
save( var1, file='~/temp/file1.rda')
```

Then in julia:

```
using DataFrames
x = read_rda("~/temp/file1.rda")
```

This returns:

```
ERROR: GZip.GZError(-1,"gzopen failed")
 in gzopen at /home/squipbar/.julia/v0.4/GZip/src/GZip.jl:250
 in gzopen at /home/squipbar/.julia/v0.4/GZip/src/GZip.jl:265
 in read_rda at /home/squipbar/.julia/v0.4/DataFrames/src/RDA.jl:418
```

I don't think that I'm doing anything dumb.  The closest I've found to this error online is in the RDatasets github  issues, here: https://github.com/johnmyleswhite/RDatasets.jl/issues/32

So perhaps this is somehow related to RDatasets?  Suggestions very welcome.

Comment: After the fact relevant links:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24841448/setting-working-directory-julia-versus-r   https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/issues/1136

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, I figured this one out.  It's the expansion of "~" in the location.  The following works:

```
using DataFrames
x = read_rda("/home/squipbar/temp/file1.rda")
```

So I guess I learnt two things here: 1) The error message for `read_rda` is not that helpful, a `File not found` message would have saved me a lot of time, and 2) that you can't use `~` in this case (is this a general thing in Julia?)

Answer (score 6):

As you found, tilde expansion is not automatic. You can use `expanduser()` to expand to the full file name.

```
julia> expanduser("~/Desktop")
"/Users/mycomputer/Desktop"
```